Are these French government departments registered as US companies?
A few months ago, a video in went viral in France, with two "sovereign citizens" refused to submit during a regular police road control. They claimed that French policemen are mercenaries on French soil, that most French government departments are US companies, and that they refuse to "contract" with them (as of "sealing a deal").
Yesterday, one of them tweeted some documents ostensibly showing multiple French departments being registered as US companies:

la holding mère REPUBLIQUE FRANÇAISE PRESIDENCE et 41200 filiales commerciales sont à vendre avec leur portefeuille "CITOYENS" clients par contrat forcé depuis la rédaction de leurs ACTES CIVILS DE NAISSANCE et la création de leurs FICTIONS JURIDIQUES ????

Auto-translation:

the parent holding company REPUBLIQUE FRANÇAISE PRESIDENCE and 41,200 commercial subsidiaries are for sale with their "CITIZENS" portfolio of customers by forced contract since the drafting of their CIVIL BIRTH CERTIFICATES and the creation of their LEGAL FICTIONS????

Here is an example of the registrations:

Some are English named French departments, listed with an address correspondence to the French Embassy in Washington. The other has a French name and French address. Each has a DUNS number.
Are these French government departments registered as US companies?

Those screen shots are without any context. It's unclear where they came from, or what kind of documents they purport to be, so it's unclear what is really being claimed. The only objective claim I see there is that those entities have been assigned DUNS numbers. I guess someone could write an answer verifying whether that's correct, and what it means.

In particular, DUNS numbers are assigned by a private company (Dun and Bradstreet) just as a way of having a unique identifier. They don't carry any official legal status that I know of (though the US government does use them, solely as identifiers, in some official processes).  To equate having a DUNS number with being "registered as a US company" is completely misleading.

Ok I thought it was some kind of official/legal registry (in the likes of the french SIREN). To go further, is there anything like that in the USA ? Some public registry of companies/business in America ?

Not that I know of.  Registration of businesses in the US is handled at the state level.

"The other has a French name and French address." What is the French name and address given? Also "The information is incorrect and you want to make changes?" reads like an English language learner asking a question.

That registered address (4101 Reservoir Road) is the address of the French Embassy in the USA. I imagine it's standard practice for embassies in the USA to set up registered companies so they can pay the correct tax on any taxable official business they do?

@NateEldredge: You are very close to an answer here. (The screenshots are from the DUNS registry.) Explaining why that is different to being registered as a company would make an answer. Consider using the SEC as the other source.

Note that the EU & NATO also use DUNS numbers sometimes. IDK if/why the French 'departments' would need it, but it doesn't imply much.

Trying to fact-check sovcits is like trying to muck out Augeas' stables except all the horses have explosive diarrhea -- no matter how much of the horse shit you shovel away, they'll keep on piling more and you'll never get anywhere.

@user56reinstatemonica8 Also so that if for some reason an American citizen (or a french citizen currently in the US) needs to communicate with them, they have a place to contact without paying for international mail.

I don't think the D-U-N-S number is needed for paying taxes (that would use an EIN instead) but it seems to be used for credit checks and stuff like that. So for instance, if the French embassy wanted to set up a contract with a local US company for food service or office supplies or whatever, on typical business payment terms (eg net 30), they might be expected to provide a D-U-N-S number. That's just a guess, though.

@Mouke all French administration entities do have a SIREN number. While the SIRENE registry constrains mostly companies, it also includes many other types of entities, including associations, administrations… basically any legal person (and natural persons as well, like all auto-entrepreneurs). Having a DUNS number just means the legal person exists.

@NateEldredge you need a DUNS number to publish an app on the Apple App Store. That gives you an idea of how common it can be for a legal person to need one.

I have a DUNS number and my company is most definitely not a US company. Everyone can get a DUNS number easily. I needed one at the time because Apple required a DUNS number to allow an app on the App Store. So if a French government office wanted an app on the App Store they’d need a DUNS number.

@user56reinstatemonica8 embassies are immune from the jurisdiction of the receiving state, including from taxation.  They don't pay taxes.  They don't engage in business activities.  It is not standard practice for an embassy to set up a company, and I would be surprised if it is even possible for an embassy to set up a company.  One reason for doing so is to be able to function as a "legal person," but embassies don't need to do that because the country they represent is already a legal person.

@jcaron not every entity with a DUNS number is a legal person.

No, they are not US companies.
Using the top right example from the image (DUNS 126952720):

The "Ministry of Economy and Finance" does have an office in the United States at 4101 Reservoir Road NW, as claimed.  The entity (which is not a company) has a DBA ('Doing Business As') identity, which is necessary to have a bank account - itself necessary for things like efficient payroll for employees. That DBA is, tellingly, "French Trade Commission."
The listed website is www.franceintheus.org, the same and top result for when you Google for "French Embassy Website."
As a matter of law, the French Embassy is required to have a legal identity in the United States in order to have operating accounts, sign leases/own property, operate vehicles, and so forth. They also hire US citizens to do work for them, which requires an EIN for income tax purposes, etc.
The existence of these do NOT mean the French Embassy is a corporation of the United States.  They are merely concessions made to the need for smooth operations, transparency, and auditability.
As noted in comments, DUNS numbers are trivially easy to acquire and are also for the purposes of transparency, ease of operations, etc. They allow anyone who wishes to contract with the DUNS registrant to have a measure of confidence in the identity and reputation thereof.
The "Edit Details" link in each of the example registrations reveals the source to be a private business directory (I'm not able to positively identify which one) - which is not an official public records repository by any means. Typically these are for-profit services that are ad-revenue and member-fee funded.
A search of the Washington DC business records (login required, but free to register) - which would contain the registration for any lawfully organized company has no record of either of the putative 'corporations' with Washington DC Addresses (see note below).  The original source has grossly misread the information and proceeds from a lack of knowledge of business law.

Note: Search terms were "French" "France" "Ministry" "Economy" (not particularly helpful) and "Finance" (also not particularly helpful by itself).
Business registrations are matters of public record in the United States. In Washington, DC particularly businesses must be registered unless they are Sole Proprietorships. These registrations are available to the public as a matter of consumer protection.  Businesses with headquarters elsewhere are required to submit Foreign Registration Statements.
Tools to search these records are routinely provided by governments who require such registrations (in this case the relevant entity is the District of Columbia).

The image text is too small to see on a number of devices (and the alt text is also completely unsuitable). You need to quote the relevant text instead.

@Laurel The relevant portions of the text are already expanded upon in the remainder of the answer - the image simply provides the capture from the DUNS lookup, which is reproduceable independently. The key pieces (website, address, DBA) are discussed as requested.

"A search of the Washington DC business records": Could you say which specific records you searched, where they can be found, and what you searched for?

@NateEldredge Public records searches feel like they should be legible as common practice, but edited per your request.

Sure. Just that "the Washington DC business records" could refer to a lot of different things, so it's good to know more specifically what you mean.

@NateEldredge Fair enough!

"As a matter of law, the French Embassy is required to have a legal identity in the United States in order to have operating accounts, sign leases/own property, operate vehicles, and so forth": nonsense.  As a matter of law, the French embassy is an arm of tbe French Republic, which has a legal identity.

Also, foreign governments that employ US citizens in the US do not withhold income tax or pay payroll tax, so they do not have an EIN.
